# How to add a web address in a AlertBox as a link?

Tags: android

I am showing a Alertbox after clicking a button. The Alert box is customised one. Along with the Alert title it has to show a web address like http://www.google.com. While clicking the web it site has to load in a seperate Activity with the content of the specific address.I am using a webview and the website is loading successfully the problem is, not able to show the web address in alertbox. It will be better if i can show it as a link.

thanks and regards 
Parvathi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String text = "<a href=http://www.google.de>Link zum klicken</a>";
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text));
```